# Should we bundle shared component library separately in lerna monorepo?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, vite, monorepo, lerna

I have three packages inside standard lerna monorepo.

1. client
2. react library
3. core

Core - is a shared component library with some utils (may or may not publish on npm).
React library is component library which will be shared on npm.
client is a bundled js library which will be consumed in browser with static html files.

core is a dependency in react-lib as well as client

Question 1 - How to setup core, should I transpile with tsc and bundle with tools such as rollup or vite (i personally prefer vite/rollup over webpack). or just leave it as is and import it in client and react-lib with absolute paths like 'core/src/*"?

Question 2 - can i build core in 'es' format and build client just like normal react app with either cra or vite. I tried this but i think i am missing something as final bundle doesn't seem to work in browser.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few questions and I might not be able to answer them all but hopefully enough to guide you for the solution you're looking for.

> Core - is a shared component library with some utils (may or may not publish on npm).

If you want to use Lerna then I guess you'll have to eventually publish the package on npm or a private repository. As an alternative, you could also use pnpm workspaces and their [`workspace:`](https://pnpm.io/workspaces#workspace-protocol-workspace) protocol which will allow you to link the packages in your workspace (monorepo) without ever downloading them from npm, for example if you use `workspace:*` then it will always use and link to the latest code from your local workspace. You could also use `workspace:` protocol with Lerna (or [Lerna-Lite](https://github.com/ghiscoding/lerna-lite)) since they both support it.

For your next Questions, I'll answer the last part of your Question 1 first because that affects the other portion of the question.

> Question 1: ...or just leave it as is and import it in client and react-lib with absolute paths like `'core/src/*'`?

Use absolute paths outside of the package is not a good thing to do since it will only work on your local project and you cannot publish that to npm since it will be broken for the other users. It's better to stick with the workspace and let the package use the `main` or `exports` entries defined in your `package.json`. In other words, it's preferable to always build/transpile and let your other package use the transpiled code and if you need to debug then make sure to also include sourcemap

> Question 1: How to setup core, should I transpile with tsc and bundle with tools such as rollup or vite (i personally prefer vite/rollup over webpack)

It probably doesn't matter which one you use TypeScript, Rollup or WebPack, In one of my project I use TypeScript in watch mode, it will auto-transpile whenever you change your code, the downside is that the more packages you have then the more TypeScript threads are opened in watch mode (1x per package) but in your case if you only have 3 then it's fine, there's also this TypeScript [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30235) that I'm following which will hopefully bring multi-threaded compilation in the future. You could also use Rollup and the concept would be the same, use it in watch mode for each package (I've done it with Vite/Rollup using `vite build --watch`
as explained in the next paragraph).

You can take a look at a project I've done [Vue 3 and pnpm workspace](https://github.com/ghiscoding/vue3-pnpm-workspace) using pnpm workspace with the `workspace:` protocol, it uses Rollup for transpiling and also uses Vite [library mode](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#library-mode) which allows to bundle your library for distribution (on npm or others...), this allows you to bundle each package as a lib that is easily reusable by other projects. It's a Vue 3 project, so it's not a React project but it should give you enough ideas on how to do in React and it should help to answer your Question 2. Also that project is not using Lerna/Lerna-Lite **but** since it uses the `workspace:` protocol then it would be super easy to add Lerna on top of it in the future (basically just adding the `lerna.json` config should be enough)

Comment: Thank a lot. I think i can see the direction now. 
i used next.js in one of my projects with next-transpile-modules which essentially treats local dep as source code and provide seamless dev experience, but it makes it difficult to know how the lib will work on it's own as I am never building or transpiling it separately

Comment: I never used React, Next, so I can't much guidance on that side... but if it helped, you can also upvote, cheers ;)